# What instrument to hedge derivatives' interest rate duration risk?

Tags: ois, eurodollars

Our market making desk is back-to-back on FX notionals, but has a residual interest rate risk measured by DV01. Currently we are using EuroDollar futures to hedge, with each contract the DV01 is $25. However we noticed the basis risk btw LIBOR and OIS. As we use OIS discounting, would it be better to hedge with other instruments such as fed funds futures?